# data not found in sqlite database table

Tags: android, sqlite

For my application i have created the sqlite database. i have added functions to add and retrieve data. i can see data added logcat message. but when receiving data it says no data found. my database code below

```
package com.burusoth1990.advertise;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="ad_details";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="advertisement";

    private static final String KEY_HEADING="heading";
    private static final String KEY_SRC="src";
    private static final String KEY_TYPE="type";
    private static final String KEY_DISTRICT="district";
    private static final String KEY_MORE="more";
    private static final String KEY_REF_ID="id";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) 
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    //create table for advertisements
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        String CREATE_AD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +KEY_REF_ID+ "TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"+ KEY_HEADING + " TEXT," + KEY_DISTRICT + " TEXT,"+  KEY_TYPE + " TEXT" +KEY_SRC + " TEXT" +  KEY_MORE+ " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_AD_TABLE);
    }

    //upgrade a existing table
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) 
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //add a advertisement into database
    public void add_ad(advertisements advertisement)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();   
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_REF_ID, advertisement._id);
        values.put(KEY_HEADING, advertisement._heading);
        values.put(KEY_DISTRICT, advertisement._district);
        values.put(KEY_TYPE, advertisement._type);
        values.put(KEY_SRC, advertisement._src);
        values.put(KEY_MORE, advertisement._more);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Log.e("ADDED","data added to database");
        db.close();
    }

    //get a specific advertisement
    public advertisements get_ad(int ref_id)
    {
        return null;
    }

    //get a advertisement from database
    public List<advertisements> get_all()
    {
        List<advertisements> ad_list=new ArrayList<advertisements>();
        String select_query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(select_query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                advertisements ad=new advertisements();
                ad.set_id(cursor.getString(0));
                ad.set_heading(cursor.getString(1));
                ad.set_district(cursor.getString(2));
                ad.set_type(cursor.getString(3));
                ad.set_src(cursor.getString(4));
                ad.set_more(cursor.getString(5));
                Log.e("DATABASE",cursor.getString(5));
                ad_list.add(ad);
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return ad_list;
    }

    //delete a advertisement from database
    public void delete_ad()
    {

    }

    //get number of advertisements in the database
    public int get_count()
    {
        String count_query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(count_query, null);
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return cursor.getColumnCount();
    }

}
```

my logcat says error while inserting

```
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778): Error inserting id=1000 more=s/s src=hi hi type=funny district=colombo heading=Testing
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table advertisement has no column named id (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO advertisement(id,more,src,type,district,heading) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at com.burusoth1990.advertise.DatabaseHandler.add_ad(DatabaseHandler.java:64)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at com.burusoth1990.advertise.Gadget_view.onCreate(Gadget_view.java:45)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-09 20:21:34.482: E/SQLiteDatabase(2778):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
```

Comment: The code you posted only appears to create the database. The functions that add data do not appear to be called by your code.

Comment: i want know is that create table sql query is right?

Comment: logcat says onCreate() method never called. do we need to call it manually.

Comment: it is my fault, problem is in sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not see any space between this texts.

```
"(" +KEY_REF_ID+ "TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"+
```

It concanated as `idTEXT PRIMARY KEY`

Secondly, you may try to write create string without these constans.

```
private static final String KEY_HEADING="heading";
    private static final String KEY_SRC="src";
    private static final String KEY_TYPE="type";
    private static final String KEY_DISTRICT="district";
    private static final String KEY_MORE="more";
    private static final String KEY_REF_ID="id";
```

Write like this;  `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST advertisement (id ... ,src ... , type ...) ";`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space:

Change:

`"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +KEY_REF_ID+ "TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"`

To:

`"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +KEY_REF_ID+ " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"`

```
                                           Missing Space here ^
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are making your SQL string much more complex by putting all the field names in static constants.

Your database oncreate will be called when you execute .getWritableDatabase. Move the call to your OpenHelper constructor as it is currently in your function that adds data but that function is unused.

Keep a reference to your database in your openhelper class rather than recreating in every data function.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have

```
...+KEY_REF_ID + "TEXT PRIMARY KEY"...
```

which is a text primary key, you should replace with the following

```
...+KEY_REF_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"...
```

Anyhow thats my suggestion it might help.

Comment: This does not answer the question. And you managed to keep the bug.

Comment: Well maybe you can not downvote a suggestion for something that you were still doing wrong.

Comment: I did not ask the question. I did downvote this answer because it is not useful (because 1. it did not answer the question that was asked, and 2. the suggestion does not even theoretically help with anything without changing other code in the app, and 3. it managed to quote the single part of the code that contains the actual bug without seeing and correcting it). I will not remove the downvote unless the answer is edited to be useful. If you just want to avoid the reputation loss, consider deleting the answer instead.